# Sign in Google Fireabase With Key SHA-1

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I would like to ask about google firebase.

> The google firebase login requires SHA-1 code. So, I took the SHA-1 code at the Gradle projects in my own laptop. It has worked steadily. When launching any application on a laptop or any other mobile device, the google firebase login function has errors. I have investigated and doubt that is the problem of SHA-1 code. I think the SHA-1 code on my friend's laptop is different from mine, which leads to inactive functionality.

Who has gone through to guide me how to fix it. This application can launch on many different phones or laptops. Please!

> Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, SHA-1 code is optional. I've never entered SHA-1 to my projects and everything still works perfectly

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong here. Firebase asks you to enter debugging SHA-1 hash when you try to add firebase to android app. It is totally optional, so if you remove that hash on firebase console, you should be fine (I've used firebase for several apps without entering that hash). I'm not sure how to remove that hash tho. Or just create a new firebase project.

Comment: Is this where you added the hash? https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-N-EknpFRuWY/WGMJsX05hrI/AAAAAAAAAtU/jLhCYAKccogEXDibSY3cUmDwdnF46R3uQCLcB/s1600/image03.png